# Passing variable from project source to form

Tags: forms, delphi, variables

I am putting some logic into the project source before form creation. If some conditions are met, I proceed  with form creation. The logic is generating data that I need to pass to the form, let'say some variable. I declared these variables inside the public section of the form, but I can't find a way to pass these values, since the variables need the form to be created to exist.
Is there a way? I am using Delphi 2007.

Comment: Why can't you create the form and set these variables?

Comment: A standard way of doing this is to have two methods in the form, `SetInterface` and `GetInterface`. After form creation and before calling `Show/ShowModal`, call `SetInterface` which transfers all parameters you want to set. When form is closed, call `GetInterface` to get the parameters from the form. To avoid too much typing, I often put all parameters in a record, and pass the record in the methods. You could do the same with properties, but that involves much typing as well, and with the `SetInterFace/GetInterface` paradigm it is clear how to use the form.

Comment: I'll explain better: I have aScheduling project that may be launched alone or by another MainForm. The on create of the scheduling runs a query whose results are shown on its window. When running the other MainForm, first thing it does it runs the same query to know whether to call the Scheduling program. In case it does not, the scheduling program is not called and does not show. Otherwise it runsu and  executes the same query again...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest to set these variables once the condition is met.

1. Run your logic
2. Check the condition
3. Create form
4. Assign variables on the form

**In the project source:**

```
var
  MyVariable1 : integer;
  MyVariable2 : integer;
begin
  Application.Initialize;
  Application.MainFormOnTaskbar := True;

  //some logic to assign variables
  //...

  //create form and set variables only if condition is met, example:
  if(MyVariable1 + MyVariable2 > 10) then
  begin
    Application.CreateForm(TForm1, Form1);
    Form1.MyVariable1 := MyVariable1;
    Form1.MyVariable2 := MyVariable2;
  end;

  Application.Run;
end.
```

**In the form source:**

```
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    MyVariable1 : integer;
    MyVariable2 : integer;
    { Public declarations }
  end;
```

Comment: Have you tested what will happen in the case the `if` statement does not execute, and you call `Application.Run` without ever creating a main form?

Comment: @KenWhite: Nothing bad happens (Delphi 2007), internally it calls "AddExitProc(DoneApplication);" before checking if the MainForm is assigned.
For this reason "DoneApplication" is executed when application terminates. "DoneApplication" hides popupmenus, hints and it calls Destroying and DestroyComponents. In his logic, some component could have been created, so I thought it was more correct to call Application.Run indipendently from the existence of a mainform.

Answer (score 1):

How you're creating the form?

You can do something like this:

```
f := TMyForm.Create(Application)
f.MyProperty := 10;
f.Show;
```

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

You can declare a global variable in form unit and use it in the form unit
you can set global var every where you want

```
TForm9 = class(TForm)
  procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
private
  { Private declarations }
public
  MyLocalVar : Int64;
end;

var
  Form9: TForm9;
  MyGlobalVar : Int64;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm9.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  MyLocalVar := MyGlobalVar;
end;
```